# In SQL I need to know how to show all of a specif value based on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have to run a leads report with very specific criteria however one of the criteria is that I anything with a 'P' in c.LN#DISP no matter what to show while also only pulling anything with an 'A' or 'T' in c.LN#DISP but only if the c.LN#NPDD is >= 10-1-2019

I have tried a bunch of diffrent ways but nothing I try seems to give me that result.

```
where 
                 (
--- Issued start   

   (i.date >= '2019-05-01' or i.date is null) 

--- Issued End

    and

---SPI Tours Start 

   (st.customer_id is null) 

--- SPI Tours End   

   and    

--- Days delinquent Start

   (p.d30 <= '6' or p.d30 is null and p.d60 <= '1' or p.d60 is null and p.d90 <= '0' or p.d90 is null)

--- Days delinquent End

                   )
   and       
             (
   ---               
                 m.knum is null
              and o.knum is null 
              and e.knum is null 
              and d.knum is null
             ) 
    and
--- Payments made start

                 (p.PMTS_Made >= '12' or p.pmts_made is null)

--- Payments made end

    and 
--- TRW and balance crieria Start           
    ((
        (
            select max(HighTrw)
            from (values (trw1), (trw2), (TRW3)) As updatedate (HighTrw)
        )  between 625 and 900  
        and c.LN#CURR#BAL between '7500' and '15000' ) 

    or 


        (
            select max(HighTrw)
            from (values (trw1), (trw2), (TRW3)) As updatedate (HighTrw)
        )  between 0 and 900  
        and c.LN#CURR#BAL is null )

--- TRW and balance criteria End

    and

--- Disp Start

        (c.LN#DISP = 'p' or (c.PBS#DISP in ('A', 'T') or c.PBS#DAYS#DELQ is null) and (c.LN#DISP in ('A', 't') or c.LN#DISP is null ))


--- Disp End

and (c.LN#NPDD >= '2019-10-1')
```

sample data

```
knum    status  state   high_trw    MF_Disp LN_Disp LN_Bal  NPDD    Pmts_Made   D30 D60 D90
52359   Full    PA  662 A   T   8890.5  11/5/2019   38  0   0   0
52359   Full    PA  677 A   T   8890.5  11/5/2019   38  0   0   0
52363   Full    PA  738 A   T   11390.97    11/5/2019   38  0   0   0
50945   Full    MD  775 A   T   9239.95 11/20/2019  66  0   0   0
50951   Full    MD  656 A   T   11902.28    11/20/2019  65  0   0   0
50952   Full    NJ  727 A   P   13411.9 8/20/2019   65  0   0   0
52379   Full    MD  654 A   P   11058.83    5/5/2019    36  0   0   0
52391   Full    NJ  645 A   T   8687.08 10/20/2019  37  0   0   0
52391   Full    NJ  653 A   T   8687.08 10/20/2019  37  0   0   0
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results and an appropriate database tag are all helpful.

Comment: I added the tags and info